# which stream should I use to transfer a custom file -like jpeg or mp3- over the network in java?

Tags: java, sockets, file-upload

I've tried to write a server and a client in java, to transfer a file. but the received file is weird and look like it's filled with strange bytes and it won't open with any application, however its size is exactly same as the source file.
I don't know where the problem is! is it about encoding?

Server-side:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class MyServer {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    char sp = File.separatorChar;
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5776);
        while (true){
            Socket connection = server.accept();
            try {
                String FileName=home+sp+"33.jpg";
                File inputFile = new File(FileName);
                FileInputStream Fin = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
                long fileLength = inputFile.length();
                byte[] bt= new byte[(int) fileLength];
                DataOutputStream Oout = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                Oout.writeLong(fileLength);
                Oout.write(bt);
                Oout.flush();
                Oout.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
            finally {
                try {
                    if(connection!= null) connection.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.err.println("There is a server on port 5776");
    }

}

}
```

Client-side:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] IP={(byte)192,(byte)168,1,7};
    char sp = File.separatorChar;
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String SharingPathString = home+sp+"File Sharing";
    String FileName = SharingPathString+sp+"file.jpg";
    try {
        InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByAddress(IP);
        Socket theSocket= new Socket("Shayan-8",5776);
        DataInputStream in= new DataInputStream(theSocket.getInputStream());
        final long FileLength = in.readLong();
        System.out.println("FileLength: "+FileLength);
        File SharingPath = new File(SharingPathString);
        if(!SharingPath.exists())
            SharingPath.mkdir();
        File outputFile = new File(FileName);
        if(outputFile.exists())
            outputFile.delete();
        //outputFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream Fos = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(Fos);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        int count=0;
        long current=0;
        while(current < FileLength && (count=in.read(buffer,0,(int)Math.min(FileLength-current, buffer.length)))!=-1)
            {Fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                current+=count;
                }
//      while((count=in.read())!=-1)
//          dos.write(count);
        dos.close();
        Fos.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        System.err.println(uhe);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        }


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't read anything *into* `bt[]`. So you are writing the correct number of null bytes.

Comment: Oh! yes,You're right! how did I forgot that?!!
Really thanks, It worked
:D

Comment: @Sathish I don't have to test your code to know that it's wrong. I've read it; i've read the Javadoc; and I've answered this question about a million times. Clearly you haven't tested it to see whether it works. When you've done that, come back and I'll tell you why, and how to fix it.